# MySQL query with date ranges

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following records:

```
    id_hotel - fecha_desde - fecha_hasta
-------------------------------------------------- ----
       4        2011-01-01    2011-01-14
       4        2011-01-05    2011-01-30
       4        2011-01-31    2011-02-07
       4        2011-02-13    2011-02-25
       3        2011-01-01    2011-03-14
       5        2011-01-01    2011-01-29
       5        2011-01-30    2011-02-27
```

And I need to make this query:

I have the date `$desde = 2011-01-04` and `$hasta = 2011-03-02`

The result I have to give is the `id_hotel` have availability at this time and in between does not find any empty day (example: id_hotel 4) that between 02/07/2011 and 13/02/2011 are 6 days that not available.

Whereupon the `id_hotel = 4` would not have to leave, but the 3 and 5.

With the example of `id_hotel = 3`, I have no problem as I use the following query:

```
SELECT       id_hotel
FROM         fechas_disponibilidad
WHERE        \''. $desde. '\' BETWEEN    fecha_desde     AND    fecha_hasta
AND          \''. $hasta.  '\' BETWEEN    fecha_desde     AND    fecha_hasta
```

I have the date from: 2011-01-04 and date up to: 03/02/2011

The result I have to give is the `id_hotel` have availability at this time and in between does not find any empty day (example: id_hotel 4) that between 02/07/2011 and13/02/2011 are 6 days that not available.

Whereupon the `id_hotel = 4` would not have to leave, but the 3 and 5.

With the example of `id_hotel = 3`, I have no problem as I use the following query:

But when I have more than one date range id_hotel column, do not know how to realize the query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done in one query. I suggest following algorithm (written in pseudo-SQL, substitute real db operations for my `select()` function):

```
$results = array();
$hotels = select("SELECT DISTINCT id_hotel FROM fechas_disponibilidad WHERE '" . $desde . "' BETWEEN fecha_desde AND fecha_hasta")
foreach ($hotels as $hotel_id) {
    $available_to = $desde;
    while ($available_to < $hasta) {
        $available_to = select("SELECT MAX(fecha_hasta) FROM fechas_disponibilidad WHERE id_hotel = " . $hotel_id . " AND '" . $availableTo . "' BETWEEN (fecha_desde - 1) AND fecha_hasta ");
        if (isNull($available_to)) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $results[] = $hotel_id;
}
```

Or create MySQL function which does the same.

Comment: Can you give me an example with mysql_query(); function??